# How to know if the player current position is the same as the live position and not behind (mediaelement.js)

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, mediaelement.js, hls.js

I am using MediaElement.js alongside Hls.js with the configuration of forcelive is set to false

```
{...,
forceLive: false
}
```

which basically allow the existence of the seek bar for live videos, i want to get the playback position and compare it to the live position.
Is that doable ?

Context: I am adding a custom button to the player with the purpose of seeking to the live playback position, the user can use the seek bar for his liking, and pressing this button will set the playback position to the live stream position